# C-like pointer in structure

Tags: rust

I'm trying to convert this simple C code to Rust:

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct n {
        int *p;
};

int main(void) {
    int i = 8;
    struct n m;

    m.p = &i;

    printf("%d ", i);
    printf("%d", *(m.p));

    return 0;
}
```

The output is "8 8".

There is no need for garbage collection or the other types of pointers which I have read about.

I've tried this:

```
struct n {
    p: *mut int
}

fn main() {
    let mut i: int = 8;
    let mut m: n;

    m.p = &i;

    println!("{} ", i);
    println!("{}", *(m.p));
}
```

But I get:

```
error: mismatched types: expected `*mut int`, found `&int` (expected *-ptr, found &-ptr).
```

Relating to this error:

```
m.p = &i;
```

There are no errors for the other lines.

I read that & is to get the address of a variable, but how can I store an address?

Answer (score 1):

Change `m.p = &i;` to `m.p = &mut i as *mut _;`

A more idiomatic way would be this though:

```
let mut m = n {
    p: &mut i
};
```

And even more idiomatic would be not using a raw pointer unless necessary.

```
struct N<'a> {
    p: &'a mut int
}
```

Comment: struct n {
 p: &mut int
} this gives error "missing lifetime specifier"

Comment: m.p = &mut i as *mut _; this gives error "dereference of unsafe pointer requires unsafe function or block"

Comment: Potentially unsafe code must be placed in an unsafe block: `unsafe { ... }`. It's not the assignment that is unsafe, but the deref later on.

Comment: Can you explain what is happening in the last example where you don't use a raw pointer?

Comment: The 'a is a lifetime. An explanation is here http://rustbyexample.com/lifetime.html

Comment: @Jimmay, you should really read [Rust guide](http://doc.rust-lang.org/guide.html), especially [the part on pointers](http://doc.rust-lang.org/guide.html#pointers). More information on references is present in a [separate guide](http://doc.rust-lang.org/guide-lifetimes.html).